# How to handle multiple Textfield input in javaFX8?

Tags: java, maven-3, javafx-8, fxml

When Unit TextField and Quantity TextField in Focus then input value should be entered accordingly.[image]

```
  void requestFocus(){
   Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            UnitText.requestFocus();
           System.out.println("Request focus thread");
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
   UnitText.requestFocus(); 
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Where is the problem?

Comment: When User click in Unit Price Textfield and press any button in calc operation should perform in Unit Price Textfield and same thing should happened with Quantity too.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly, but I think you need to add onClick Listener

Comment: If I do in onClick listener of buton how can I know in which TextField user want to enter mean which is focued textFied right now.

Comment: Check with IF-loop which textField is focused and then do what you want to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
private TextField lastFocusedTextField ;

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    lastFocusedTextField = unitText ;

    unitText.focusedProperty().addListener((obs, wasFocused, isNowFocused) -> {
        if (isNowFocused) {
            lastFocusedTextField = unitText ;
        }
    });

    quantityText.focusedProperty().addListener((obs, wasFocused, isNowFocused) -> {
        if (isNowFocused) {
            lastFocusedTextField = quantityText;
        }
    });



}
```

And now in your button handlers do

```
@FXML
public void handleButton() {
    // process button press in lastFocusedTextField...
}
```

Comment: It works :) but I can't get obs and wasFocused param.

Comment: I don't understand that comment

Comment: we're checking which field focused in only initialize method then how can it gives answer every time when any textField get focused?

Comment: Because it's a listener added to the `focusedProperty()`.

Comment: what does this parameter do i.e obs, wasFocused

Comment: They are parameters to the `ChangeListener`'s `changed` method: i.e. a reference to the property that changed and the old value of the property. (`isNowFocused` is the new value of the property). Did you read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/value/ChangeListener.html#changed-javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue-T-T-)?